# editing property of the (initial) state in the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to change an element of an array that is in my initialState in the reducer.

I have read that i should use Object.assign(), then i only get to change the entire array.

```
const initState = {
    features:  [
        {id:1, title: 'Information is aviable everywhere', visible:true, status:2, next:2, points: 0},
        {id:2, title: 'Information is aviable everywhere v2', visible:false, status:2, next:3, points: 0},
        ...
```

this is my current method of doing it, however, it changes the array order... therefore is displayed in a different order:

```
    case 'TEST_FEATURE':
        let newFeatures = state.features.filter(feature => {
            return action.feature.id !== feature.id && action.feature.next !== feature.id
            })
        let nexFeature =  state.features.find(feature => {
        return feature.id === action.feature.next})

        nexFeature.visible = true  
        newFeatures.unshift(nexFeature)    
        return {
            ...state,
            features: newFeatures
        }
```

I want to change feature id 2, (only the atribute) visibile=true and have the same arrays order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you don't want to be doing this in your reducer, as it should be pure, but to achieve what you want you could just do something like:

```js
const newState = state.features.reduce((acc, feature) => {
    if(action.feature.id !== feature.id){
        feature.visible = !feature.visible;
    }
    return [ ...acc, feature ];
}, [])
```

This would maintain the order, change the value, clone the state, and avoid the other loops you're doing.

Comment: thanks! since im learning, if im not supouse to do that in the reducer, where should I?

Comment: Ideally some container component that is connected to the redux store. You handle the logic there, and dispatch an action with the "payload" - the payload being the new state.